# How to open a Java Web Start Application from a Hyperlink in a JavaFX 2.0 Application

Tags: javafx-2

I have a web application that loads other applications from within it, how can I open a java web start application from within my JavaFx 2.0 application. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's long to answer, you need to study how to [Deploy Java Web Start application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html) first.

The basic approach is:

1. Create a JAR file containing your application's class files and resources. including Main-Class attribute in your MANIFEST.MF.
2. Create JNLP files to describe how your application to run, You can also use [JavaFX Packager tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/packager001.htm) to help.

Then look at source code for [The Java FX Ensemble example](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.0.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html) to figure out JavaFX specific configuration, and full documentation [Deploying JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm).